# White screen when i try to use filter vue js 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects, vuejs3

I have a todo list, i'm trying to display the todos that are not done yet like this
`<p id="todosLeft"> {{ todos.value.filter(item => item.done).length }} items left</p><!-- Add dynamic number -->` it does not show error but it shows white page like this [image: white-screen]
does anybody know the proplem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using a ref property which could be accessed without using `value` in template section :

```
<p id="todosLeft"> {{ todos.filter(item => item.done).length }} items left</p>
```

But I recommend to return a computed property like :

```
import {computed, ref} from 'vue'
...
setup(){
    ...
   return{
    todos, todosLength:computed(()=>todos.value.filter(item => item.done).length)
   }
}
```

then use it directly in template :

```
<p id="todosLeft"> {{ todosLength }} items left</p>
```

Comment: it worked thank you,.  so we only use `.value ` in  setUp() ?

Comment: Yes only in setup hook